# My code prints a hex that is not valid for an image, it's not a value from the array that I am comparing. I don't understand where is coming from

Tags: arrays, c, image, printf, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    // open image
    FILE *image = fopen("me.jpg", "r");
    // read image
    // check if file is NULL
    if(image == NULL) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    // store char signature in array
    unsigned char signature[4];
    // store extra
    unsigned char extra[16] = 
    {
      0xe0, 0xe1, 0xe2, 0xe3, 0xe4, 0xe5, 0xe6, 0xe7,
      0xe8, 0xe9, 0xea, 0xeb, 0xec, 0xed, 0xee, 0xef
    };
    // read signature
    fread(signature, 4, 1, image);
    // read extra
    char extrahex = fread(extra, 16, 1, image);
    // find extra in the image
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
    {
        if(extra[i] == extrahex)
        {
            printf("%#04x\n", extrahex);
            return 0;
            char hexnum = extrahex;
            // condition for jpeg
            if(signature[0] == 0xff && signature[1] == 0xd8 && signature[2] == 0xff && signature[3] == hexnum) 
            {
                printf("valid jpeg format\n");
            } 
            else 
            {
                printf("not a valid jpeg format\n");
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    fclose(image);
}
```

the return value that is printed is: 0x01, this is not a value from the extra array that I am checking against the image.
And of course, the result is "not a valid jpg format". I tried a different image, it prints the same 0x01 value.

[image]

Comment: @Oka can you please not destroy the formating and making it less readable? It was better before.

Comment: @1243 Zero indentation was more readable? Interesting. A minor change to brace styling is hardly "destroying the formatting".

Comment: @Oka Yes it was, it was bad but not as bad as it was after you edited it. At least the `{` and the corresponding `}` lined up before. After you edited it, they didn't.

Comment: @1243 You have made modifications that were not present in the original example, but are present in the screenshot (two comments).

Comment: Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? In week 2 of CS50, you were taught how to use a debugger. Note that [the lesson of week 2 has a chapter named "Debugging"](https://video.cs50.io/XmYnsO7iSI8?screen=5YGV1hcM_MY&start=2294&end=3777). Week 2 also has a few short videos on debugging.

Comment: Have you read the [manual for `fread`](https://manual.cs50.io/3/fread)? `extrahex` will be the number of *items* read (hence 1), and is probably not what you are looking to compare with.

Comment: @Gerhardh `if(extra[i]` *is* used, and the bytes read *may* contain 0x1 (which correlates with their observation of the printed value).

Comment: @Oka right, missed that one.

Comment: I need to figure out how to read the value of that one item that I am getting at 0x01 and compare it to the value of signature[4]. Maybe that will solve my problem. So yes, debug and work with pointers. If you have a Idea to share, on how to get to the value that I'm looking for, please .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to make another call to `fread`. Instead, you must check if `signature[3]` is one of the known values stored in `extra`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *image = fopen("me.jpg", "r");

    if (!image)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned char signature[4];
    unsigned char extra[16] = {
        0xe0, 0xe1, 0xe2, 0xe3, 0xe4, 0xe5, 0xe6, 0xe7,
        0xe8, 0xe9, 0xea, 0xeb, 0xec, 0xed, 0xee, 0xef
    };

    fread(signature, 4, 1, image);
    fclose(image);

    if (signature[0] == 0xff && signature[1] == 0xd8 && signature[2] == 0xff)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            if (signature[3] == extra[i])
            {
                puts("valid jpeg format");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    puts("not a valid jpeg format");
}
```

Alternatively, check that the first four bits of `signature[3]` are `1110` (`0xe`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *image = fopen("me.jpg", "r");

    if (!image)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned char signature[4];

    fread(signature, 4, 1, image);
    fclose(image);

    if (signature[0] == 0xff &&
        signature[1] == 0xd8 &&
        signature[2] == 0xff &&
        (signature[3] >> 4) == 0xe)
    {
        puts("valid jpeg format");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("not a valid jpeg format");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example worked fine but would you mind explaining this line: (signature[3] >> 4) & 0xe. I don't understand it.

Comment: Sorry, the binary AND was a mistake - it should check for equivalence. `signature[3] >> 4` [*shifts*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Shift_operators) the binary representation of `signature[3]` to the *right* by four bits. For example, `0xec` is `11101100`, which means `0xec >> 4` is `00001110`. `00001110` is `0xe` (or `0x0e` if it's easier to visualize). In other words, the upper four bits become the lower four bits, and the upper four bits are replaced with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread the return value of **fread** is the number of full items the function read. In your case you try to read 1 element of 16 bytes in size. So **extrahex** will always be 0x01.

Just a guess: you might want **char extrahex = signature[3]** instead

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the example of Oka. Interesting though, I played with addresses and pointers and still got 1 as return in printf.[image: pointers and addresses]